# On the assumptions of linear regression

Tags: regression, assumptions

After reading several notes on this topic, there's one point that I seem to miss. Most texts assume these hypothesis in a linear regression model:

- $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\varepsilon$
- $\varepsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$
- $Var(\varepsilon_{|X=x})=\sigma^2$ for every $x$
- The errors are indepedent of each other

From these assumptions, some texts conclude that the distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is normal with mean $\beta_0+\beta_1x$ and variance $\sigma^2$. However, if I'm not missing something, shouldn't we impose an extra assumption of independence between $X$ and $\varepsilon$ in order to claim this?

Comment: Isn't this implied by "The errors are indepedent of each other"?

Comment: Do they perhaps treat the X's as fixed constants rather than random variables?

Comment: Is it not the case that if errors were not independent of the X's, then the distribution of the errors would depend on the distribution of the X's leading to breach of the second assumption?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The errors can be identically distributed yet highly dependent. An extreme example would be the case where $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=\cdots=\epsilon_n$ and $\epsilon_1$ could be correlated with say, $X_1$.

Comment: @Glen_b They start by defining a model with "random design", which is the one above, and then they define a model with "fixed design", that is, setting $X=x$. What I don't know is whether they fix $x$ as a constant and then assume the same list of hypothesis changing $X$ by $x$, or if they are conditioning the model with "random design" to $X=x$, which seems to be the natural thing to do.

Comment: Thanks. Could you perhaps link to an example of (or give a reference to) what you're discussing so we can all be on the same page?